# Passing a pointer to one C function as a parameter to another function

Tags: ruby, ffi

I am using the [FFI gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/ffi) so that I can access function in a C library directly from my [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/) program.  If the C library has one function that accepts a function pointer argument, and it has a second function that has the right signature to be in that argument, then how do I pass a pointer to the second function as an argument to the first function?

## What I tried

Here is what I have tried so far.  To simplify things, I wrote my own very simple C library in a file named `bar.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef int bar_func();

int bar1()
{
    return 7;
}

int bar2(bar_func * f)
{
    printf("f=%p, bar2=%p\n", f, bar1);
    return f() + f();
}
```

I compiled it under Arch Linux by running `gcc -std=gnu99 -fPIC -shared bar.c -o bar.so`

My goal is to pass a pointer to `bar1` as an argument to `bar2`.  I would expect `bar2` to print two identical pointers and then return 14.

So I ran this program using Ruby 2.2.0p0 and ffi 1.9.6:

```
require 'ffi'

module Bar
  extend ::FFI::Library
  ffi_lib './bar.so'
  callback :bar_func, [], :int
  attach_function :bar1, [], :int
  attach_function :bar2, [:bar_func], :int

  puts bar2(method(:bar1))   # => 14
end
```

When I run the program, here is the output I get:

```
f=0x7f563ce46000, bar1=0x7f563af7d6e0
14
```

It gives the right return value, but you can see that the function pointer passed into the `bar2` function is clearly not equal to `bar1`, because the two function pointers printed on the first line are different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saw a hint in the [FFI::Library documentation](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/ffi/ffi/FFI/Library).  It says that `attach_function` returns a `FFI::VariadicInvoker` object.  I made an educated guess that you could pass that in instead of a proc, and it worked.

```
module Bar
  extend ::FFI::Library
  ffi_lib './bar.so'
  callback :bar_func, [], :int
  Bar1Invoker = attach_function :bar1, [], :int
  attach_function :bar2, [:bar_func], :int

  puts bar2(Bar1Invoker)   # => 14
end
```

I got the desired output:

```
f=0x7f949ed7d6e0, bar1=0x7f949ed7d6e0
14
```

I have edited the [Callbacks](https://github.com/ffi/ffi/wiki/Callbacks) page on the FFI wiki to have this information.